# Get Parent node of a given node using SQL hierarchyId

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy

I have a table as CorporateStructure as following with following data:

```
╔════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ Id ║  Name  ║ HierarchyId ║
╠════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ john   ║ /           ║
║  2 ║ smith  ║ /1          ║
║  3 ║ John2  ║ /1/1/       ║
║  4 ║ Collin ║ /1/1/1      ║
╚════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

Id i have id 4 and i want to find the parent how can i do that?

Regards
Vishal

Comment: Is `/1/1/1` really the literal value in `HierarchyId`?

Comment: /1/1/1 is the string value of the HierarchId

Answer (score 3):

As Michael has pointed out the literal value for smith (`/1`) and Collin (`/1/1/1`) doesn't seem to be a valid `HierarchyId`

Correcting those values you can get the parent node using `GetAncestor`

Try this :-

```
Select * from YourTable
where [HierarchyId] in (
           Select [HierarchyId].GetAncestor([HierarchyId].GetLevel()-1).ToString()
           from YourTable
           where id=4
           )
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22211/4) Demo

Comment: Note that your GetAncestor call will get the root node, and not the immediate parent of the node. The parameter of GetAncestor is n where n represents the number of levels to go up the hierarchy. To get the immediate parent just do GetAncestor(1).